# ip neigh show on android 13 device returns exitcode 1

Tags: android, android-studio

I developed simple custom app to query some custom devices connected to my local hotspot on my mobile to check temperature, speed and so on. Till android 12 I used `runtime.exec('ip neigh show')` setting `compileSdkVersion 29` , `buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'` , `minSdkVersion 21` and `targetSdkVersion 27` and it worked perfectly retrieving IP of connected devices.
Now I used an android 13 device and debugging on `runtime.exec('ip neigh show')` it returns `ExitCode = 1` which means on android 13 devices there is strict restriction on /proc/net/arp file which is read from ip neigh show command I suppose.

Is there an alternative to query my own hotspot to retrieve connected device's IP with android 13+ devices?....

EDIT: for now the only thing I can retrieve on android 13 device is the IP of hotspot with:

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress( wifiInfo.getIpAddress() );
```

where I can read the IP of the device. Maybe is there a way to query that IP to retrieve connected devices IP without using `ip neigh show`?

EDIT 2 : after some investigation and trying this to check CONNECTIVITY_MANAGER with this code sample:

```
Network[] allNetworks = connectivityManager.getAllNetworks();
for (Network network: allNetworks) {
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network);
    LinkProperties lp = connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(network);
    String id = lp.getInterfaceName();
    Log.d("IdInfo", "id: " + id);
}
```

I see only `MOBILE[LTE]` connectivity in debug but also hotspot should be a connectivity host I suppose... or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I approached a different way to reach my goal not being based on `arp file` or `connectivityManager` but *knowing the mask of domain so then check all 255 IPs of that domain*. I think at this time Android completely closed arp file or even querying it own mobile hotspot devices due to security. Obviously except if using an older android version device.